# "Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number"

Tags: excel, powerbi

[image]

I want to use the Site URL and year and concatenate using M code and then generate the data.

My aim is if i change the year, it will automatically update the details from the URL.

I have attached a image of the code which i done and it shows the error attached.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `URL&Number.ToText(Year)`